# Retain loop in a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

I'm trying to get variables and properties in `self` in a block for actions to complete, but, if I reference `self` or a global variable in `self` when `self` is the object running the block, it warns me of a retain loop. Here's what I'm doing:

- I'm adding actions to an `NSMutableArray` that are of type `(void(^)()` (in other words, a block returning `void` with no parameters).
- I call it using this syntax later on, where `i` is an `int` determined by code (that is in the bounds of the array:

  void (^someBlock)() = arrayOfActions[i];
  someBlock();

The code works and runs fine, but, because I use properties of `self` **within the block**, Xcode warns me of a retain loop. Should I ignore it because it's simply a warning and everything works fine in code (it only executes the block once), or should I do something different?

Comment: I am a little confused by what your block declaration is. Looks like `someBlock` does absolutely nothing?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin : `someBlock` is a block in `arrayOfActions` at index `i` that has already been programmed and added in, and then I call `someBlock()` to execute it.

Comment: But *who* holds onto this `arrayOfActions`? That is the real question. Otherwise, there is no reason to believe there's a retain cycle.

Comment: @newacct it was a variable in the implementation of `self`. I simply put my methods in a delegate class instead of dealing with blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely **not ignore** the warning, but use `__weak` instead to define a weak reference and eliminate retain cycles as described [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16):

```
__weak SelfType *weakSelf = self;

void (^aBlock)() = ^(){
    SelfType *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    //User strongSelf
};
```

Alternatively you can use libextobjc  (https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc) with its convenient `@strongify` and `@weakify` annotations.